# Using WAMP: Read file permissions on Windows

Tags: php, windows-xp

my system : windos xp

I have given all the permission to all user for file.

but i can not read file but I get filesize,

why this thing happen, reason i can not identify.

what should i do to over come  this problem.

Code

```
$fileName = "1.php";

if (floatval(phpversion()) >= 4.3) {

  //loading data
  $fileData = file_get_contents($fileName);
  print(filesize($fileName));

} else {

  //if file not exist then return -3
  if (!file_exists($fileName)) {
    eturn -3;
  }

  $fp = fopen($fileName, 'r');
  // if file is not open in read mode then return -2
  if (!$fp) return -2;

  $fileData = '';
  print(filesize($fileName));

  //checking end of file
  while(!feof($fp))
    $fileData .= fgetc($fileName);

  fclose($fp);

}

echo $fileData;
```

Comment: try starting the wamp server as administrator

Comment: first of all try to find out what the error message is.

Comment: no error , no notice, no warning. Just displaying file size but not content.

Comment: Please post code that actually parses...

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are:

- `eturn` should say `return` - this is probably a parse error
- **The actual problem** is that you are calling `fgetc($fileName)` when it should be `fgetc($fp)`. You are passing the string of the filename to `fgetc()` instead of the file pointer your created.

Change:

```
$fileData .= fgetc($fileName);
```

To

```
$filedata .= fgetc($fp);
```